# Fast random string

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, random

I'm trying to generate random string ID for a program (the ID has to be unique only during the execution of the program). I first did it in Python without any issue:

```
class RandomIdGenerator:
    _base_62_chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    @classmethod
    def get_base_62(cls, length):
        return "".join([random.choice(RandomIdGenerator._base_62_chars) for _ in range(length)])
```

But as I need my program to be in C++, I'm trying to generate the same string with it. This is what I do now:

```
void Node::setId()
{
    QString allow_symbols("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789");
    qsrand(QTime::currentTime().msec());

    for (int i = 0; i < ID_LENGTH; ++i) {
        id_.append(allow_symbols.at(qrand() % (allow_symbols.length())));
    }
}
```

I have two main issues with it. First it doesn't use C++11 (I don't know how Qt works but I don't think it's C++11) and the ID generated are all the same. If I generate four of them I get:

```
"R4NDM1xM"
"R4NDM1xM"
"R4NDM1xM"
"R4NDM1xM"
```

I tried using the C++11 method but I got the same result, even worse, at each execution, I got the exact same result:

```
void Node::setId()
{
    id_ = "";

    const std::string str = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 generator(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, str.size() - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < Node::ID_LENGTH; ++i)
        id_ += str[dist(generator)];
}
```

**How can I generate random string ID at each call of a method?**

Comment: Seed the generator **only once**, at the start of your program.

Comment: Pseudo random generators generate hardly predictable but the same sequence for the same seed. Do not seed it every time.

Comment: Okay if I do `qsrand(QTime::currentTime().msec());` only once at the start it works. But how to do this using C++11?

Comment: Re: "do this using C++11" -- same thing. Seed `generator` only once.

Comment: *"the ID has to be unique"* your random strings are not guarantied to be unique Btw.

Comment: Why does it have to be *random*? If it is enough to be *unique* then an incrementing value would be extremely quick.

Comment: Because I have to save these id into a different file and be able to load any object from the file with the correct id. If I use incremental values, and I load two different files it will break because some of the following ids will be the same. So much easier with 12 chars random IDs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Random number generators should only be seeded once unless you need to repeat a "ramdom" sequence again.  That means that `qsrand(QTime::currentTime().msec());` should only be called the first time you enter `setId()`.  This is a little tricky since it is a function call but you can add a static `bool` variable to keep track of if it has been ran and if it has then don't call it again.  Something like

```
void Node::setId()
{
    static bool seeded = false;
    QString allow_symbols("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789");
    if (!seeded) 
    {
        qsrand(QTime::currentTime().msec());
        seeded = true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ID_LENGTH; ++i) {
        id_.append(allow_symbols.at(qrand() % (allow_symbols.length())));
    }
}
```

The C++11 code is even easier.  Since the random generator is an object you can make it static and it will only be initialized the first time the function is called.  That means your code becomes:

```
void Node::setId()
{
    id_ = "";
    id_.reserve(Node::ID_LENGTH); // preallocate storage

    static const std::string str = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::mt19937 generator(rd());
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, str.size() - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < Node::ID_LENGTH; ++i)
        id_ += str[dist(generator)];
}
```

---

It should also be noted that `std::random_device` is backed by a non deterministic source.  If your implementation does not support that then it is possibly for `std::random_device` to produce the same sequence every time you call it.  If that is the case then you will have to use another option to seed `generator` like using the current time.